# How is thread getting killed inside try-catch block?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, try-catch, jstack

I have one thread-1 that is infinitely running.

```
public void run(){
    while (true)
    {
      try
      {
        serverSocket.receive(packet);
        processReceivedPacket();
      }
      catch (Exception x){ }
    }
}
```

I have 10 other threads. After running this application for a while I can see that my application is running but this thread-1 is not running anymore.

```
jstack -l pid >> stack.txt
```

When I take a stack of the process I can see the other threads, not this thread-1.

Is it possible that JVM is killing this thread even after try-catch block?

If the thread is not dead then how to find out which line the thread-1 is currently executing. Jstack is not working. In the Jstack file, there is no information for this thread-1.

Comment: One of the possibility is exception from catch block

Comment: Another possibility is that an `Error` like `OutOfMemoryError` or `StackOverflowError` is thrown inside the try block - `Error` and it's subclasses are not subclasses of `Exception` and are therefore not caught.

Comment: @ThomasKläger, thanks for the comment. You should probably write your comment as an answer and a little bit more details.

Another question I was running my application with java -Xmx8192m -jar option. so if OutOfMemoryError occurs then shouldn't it just kill the whole process not just this thread?

Comment: Even with an error thrown, a thread will not disappear. Undhandled errors and exceptions are printed to STDERR before the thread ends. Just a hint, because I don't know if you tried to provide a small example: avoid catching "Exception" if there are better options and avoid empty catch blocks.